# Text-align attribute in HTML / CSS / ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to align my text on the right of my div element, but it's not working. I've tried `text-align: right` and `width: 100%` but this not seems to solve the problem.
I think that all the problem is into the `left-side` and the `right-side` attributes, but I can't figure out what the problem is...
Here is my code :

```css
.left-block {
  width: 50%;
  height: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

.selected-file {
  color: #12073C;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.left-side {
  text-align: left;
}

.right-side {
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}

.small-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}
```

```html
<div className="left-block">
  <div className="file-informations">
    <div className="small-title">File Information</div>

    <div className="file-values">
      <span className="left-side">File Size</span>
      <span className="right-side"><b>{this.humanFileSize(this.state.fileSize)}</b></span><br/> File category <b>{this.state.type}</b><br/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="merging-informations">
    <div className="small-title">
      Merging statistics
    </div>

    <div className="merging-values">
      <b>Primary Key</b> <br/> o/w New Lease <br/> o/w New Well <br/> o/w Existing <br/>
      <b>o/w Conflicted</b> <br/> o/w Distric Name <br/> o/w Field2 <br/> o/w Field3 <br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The html attribute for classes is `class` not `className` or are you using any framework that is relying on `className` to be an attribute in HTML?

Comment: Yes it's ReactJS, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` elements are inline – which means they can't use `text-align` left or right.

You should look into either using floats:

```
.file-values {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-side {
  float: left;
}

.right-side {
  float: right;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Or look into using Flexbox on the container, I think something as simple as:

```
.file-values {
  display: flex;
}
```

Would begin to get the layout you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The `text-align` works, but your container is `span` which is an inline element. By default it takes the widths it needs so your content will fit, if you'll set a wider width and set `display:block` you'll see your text align to the left/right.

In my opinion. in your case you should just use `div`s which by default have a display block.

I also suggest not using the `<b>` and instead use CSS for it: `font-weight: bold`

```css
.left-block {
  width: 50%;
  height: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

.selected-file {
  color: #12073C;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.left-side {
  text-align: left;
}

.right-side {
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}

.small-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-block">
  <div class="file-informations">
    <div class="small-title">File Information</div>

    <div class="file-values">
      <div class="left-side">File Size</div>
      <div class="right-side"><b>{this.humanFileSize(this.state.fileSize)}</b></div><br/> File category <b>{this.state.type}</b><br/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="merging-informations">
    <div class="small-title">
      Merging statistics
    </div>

    <div class="merging-values">
      <b>Primary Key</b> <br/> o/w New Lease <br/> o/w New Well <br/> o/w Existing <br/>
      <b>o/w Conflicted</b> <br/> o/w Distric Name <br/> o/w Field2 <br/> o/w Field3 <br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` you are using is inline element, so its width depends on content's size.
What we can do is add property `display: inline-block` and we will get possibility to change its width.

Size of its closest parent with fixed width `.left-block` is 50% width of body, so when we will give it `width: 100%;` it will be size of `.left-block`.

After changing its display mode, we will be able to align text as we want to.

Here's code example:

```
.right-side {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}
```

[Please take a look on working example of this (I converted it to HTML/CSS but it's minor change in this case).](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-on8cl)

Answer (score 0):

try `display:flex` like  tis:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}
.left-block {
  width: 50%;
  height: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

.selected-file {
  color: #12073C;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}
.file-values{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.right-side{
  margin-left:auto;
}

.small-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-block">
  <div class="file-informations">
    <div class="small-title">File Information</div>

    <div class="file-values">
      <span class="left-side">File Size</span>
      <span class="right-side"></span>File category
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="merging-informations">
    <div class="small-title">
      Merging statistics
    </div>

    <div class="merging-values">
      <b>Primary Key</b> <br/> o/w New Lease <br/> o/w New Well <br/> o/w Existing <br/>
      <b>o/w Conflicted</b> <br/> o/w Distric Name <br/> o/w Field2 <br/> o/w Field3 <br/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```